# how to find which type of extreme comes first in time series

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing

I want to find which type of extreme comes first in random time series in python language. For instance, the first extreme is maximum or minimum?
for the first steps I wrote this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
ds = np.random.randn(50)
rd = [0]
for i in ds:
    rd.append(rd[-1]*0.3 + i)
df = pd.DataFrame(rd, columns=['data'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean global minimum and maximum, try comparing these values:

```
df.data.values.argmin(), df.data.values.argmax()
```

If you mean first local min & max, you may compare the first and the second values:

- if the second value is less than the first, the first local extreme is min
- if the seond value is greater than the first, the first local extreme is max
- otherwise (equal) test the next value